# rsync: Excluding pattern in exclude file desn't work

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to exclude all vim backup files (hidden *.swp files) from the sync.
The pattern in my exclude file looks like this:

```
**.swp
```

My rsync call:

```
rsync -ravu --exclude=~/sync/exclude.txt /home/username/Documents/ remotehost:/home/username/Documents/
```

The file sits in a subdirectory of the sync root.
It deosn't work. Rsync copies the vim backup file as well.
I also tried: *.swp

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `--exclude=` expect the patters themselves.  `--exclude-from=` is how you specify the file that has patterns into it.  Also, why are you using **.swp instead of *.swp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `--exclude` (which expects a pattern) rather than `--exclude-from` (which expects the name of a file containing patterns).

You also do not need `-r` (`--recursive`) with `-a` (`--archive`) as `-a` enables recursive syncing. In fact, `-a` is the same as `-rlptgoD` according to the manual.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `**` and for a single pattern you might as well just use `--exclude`. The `--include` pattern ensures that directories matching the `--exclude` pattern are included in the copy.

```
rsync -a  --include '*/' --exclude='.*.swp' /home/username/Documents/ remotehost:/home/username/Documents/
```

If your remote username has `/home/username` as its home directory you can further simplify with a relative path:

```
rsync -a  --include '*/' --exclude='.*.swp' /home/username/Documents/ remotehost:Documents/
```

Bear also in mind that `vim` will use other filenames for its swap file if one matching `*.swp` already exists or is in use. But you'll catch most of them with this single pattern. Here's what the documentation warns:

> If this file already exists (e.g., when you are recovering from a crash) a
>     warning is given and another extension is used, ".swo", ".swn", etc.

You could adapt the exclusion pattern to use `.*.sw[a-p]` if you were sufficiently concerned.